# .cs files, projects and solutions

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, csproj

Given I have a file in a TFS source code repository. I'm trying to discover programatically which cs project this file belongs to and then which other projects\solutions rely on the output of that project.

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: **Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow**

Comment: Ok I've edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `csproj` files are Xml based files, so you can symply open the file, process the Xml and search for the file.
For files, you can find if a file is included in the project by searching in  them searching for the Tag `ItemGroup` and within `ItemGroup` the Tag `Compile`, if the file is for compilation, if not search within `GroupItem` the `None` or other according to the file nature

For searching for referenced projects you have to search in `GroupItem` Tags about `ProjectReference` Tag

There is other useful tags like Content for resources, None...etc.

I encourage you to open your `csproj` in notepad++ and see what you can find, it is pretty simple.

Answer (score 2):

**proj** files are XML files, if you parse them you would find all the project files under `ItemGroup`. You might find multiple `ItemGroup` elements. Some has children of type `Compile`, `Contents`...etc So I would suggest that you check a couple of them to have an idea of what I am talking about. **cs** files will most likely be under `Compile`

For your project dependencies, I never did that before, but if the dependencies are *declared* in your solution, then in every project you should find a `ProjectReference` to the other projects it depends on.

In conclusion, you need to parse the project files XML then query for your source files and project dependencies.